# How can Power Automate make an option unavailable in a Microsoft Forms drop-down question?

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, power-automate

How can Power Automate make an option unavailable in a Microsoft Forms drop-down question when a certain number of respondents have chosen that option?

From OneDrive, I created a Forms for Excel, then I created the Forms with a question containing a drop-down list. The responses to the form are automatically compiled in the Excel file.
Now, I want to add a counter that will allow me to automatically remove an option from the drop-down list if it is chosen for example 20 times.

Comment: There are no REST API’s to configure a form so you’re kinda stuck.